# Close as duplicate *after* I voted to close before question was edited

Tags: feature-request, exact-duplicates, closing

I'm aware the title is rather unclear. Couldn't manage to formulate it correctly.

I actually found this question:

[Half Bridge with dual powre supply and two N-channel Mosfets?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/242033/half-bridge-with-dual-powre-supply-and-two-n-channel-mosfets)

is similar to this one, which was asked previously:

[Is it possible to build an H-Bridge with only N-MOSFETs (and these other components)?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/196203/is-it-possible-to-build-an-h-bridge-with-only-n-mosfets-and-these-other-compone/196207#196207)

So, naturally, I went to close it as duplicate, so we can vote, etc... Unfortunately, I forgot it, but I had already voted to close it (as unclear), before an edit was made to make it more clear ([timeline](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/242033/timeline)). So I can't do it.

I really think it is a duplicate. Shouldn't the fact that the question has been edited be relevant, and allow me to cast a new "close as duplicate" vote, although I already casted a close vote before? I mean, the question wasn't formulated the same at that time, and the close reason is different.

Maybe this belongs to the main meta, as well. Not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community review is purposely designed to prevent any one user from dominating the process. Therefore, each user only gets to vote on a post just once.

Yes, that means that you'll sometimes get locked out in a situation like this. The most you can do at this point is to leave a comment that will guide other reviewers in the right direction. Or if you think it's urgent enough, raise a moderator flag on it and explain what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I can accept the way it is designed. Not sure leaving a comment will have an effect, though, since it will probably be missed by everbody, this question now being a few weeks old. But, you are a moderator, so, if you agree with the duplicate judgment, you may want to fix that question eventually.